# Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,ANY> to Map<String,List<String>>

Tags: apex

First i will have a JSON String:

```
{"API_Name__c":["values 1","value2"],"API_Name2__c":["value3","value4"]}
```

Here is my apex controller:

```
public static List<Object> getObject(String filter) {
System.debug('Here is String of map: ' + filter);
        Map<String, List<String>> filterMap = ( Map<String, List<String>>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(filter);
        System.debug('Here is map: ' + filterMap);
}
```

It will give me this Error:

```
Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,ANY> to Map<String,List<String>>
```

How should i fix this? Thanks for helping!

Comment: you can also use deserialize instead of deserializeUntyped
         Map<String, List<String>> filterMap = ( Map<String, List<String>>)JSON.deserialize(filter,  Map<String,List<String>>.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm), `JSON.deserializeUntyped` will return an collections of primitive data types, which is primitive `Object`, that may be `List<Object>` or `Map<String, Object>`. So, unfortunately, you can not perform desired operation as is, but you can do the following steps:

1. Get Map as a first step of deserializing
2. Get List as second step

Code

```
public static List<Object> getObject(String filter) {
    System.debug('Here is String of map: ' + filter);
    Map<String, Object> parent_map = ( Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(filter);
    System.debug('Here is Parent map: ' + parent_map);
    for(String key : parent_map.keySet()) {
        if (parent_map.get(key) instanceof List<Object>) {
            List<Object> values = (List<Object>)parent_map.get(key);
            System.debug('Here is List of key "'+key+'" :' + values);
        } else {
            // handle a case if that is primitive, or other Map
        }
    }
}
```